# How to fix Text returning instance of " " instead of the actual value?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

This is my second post on this issue. I havent been able to figure this out due to my limited dart knowledge. I always screw up with the futures part.
Here's the code that's the issue:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:slide_journal/Database_.dart';


class ListOfEntries extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(30))),
       title: Text("Your entries"),
       toolbarHeight: 50,
     ),
     body: FutureBuilder<List>(
       future: Database_().entries(),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
         return snapshot.hasData ?
         new ListView.builder(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
           itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
           itemBuilder: (context, i) {
             return Column(
               children: [
                 Text("${snapshot.data[i]}"),
               ],
             );
           },
         )
             : Center(
           child: Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
             children: [
               CircularProgressIndicator(),
               Text(""),
               Text("No entries yet:("),
             ],             
           
           )
         );
       }
    ),

    );

  }
  

}
```

Here's the reference for the read from database part:

```
Future<List<Entry_>> entries() async {
    final Database db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('[Journal Entries]');
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Entry_ (
        maps[i]["_entry"],
        maps[i]["_date"],
      );
    });
  }
```

Instead of showing the items in the list it shows:
"Instance of 'Entry_
'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in an `Entry` object into a text widget. You need to grab the values from the `Entry` object.

Assuming your `Entry` class looks like this.

```
class Entry {
  final String entry;
  final String date;

  Entry({this.entry, this.date});
}
```

Then in order to pass an actual String into a text widget you do this.

```
Text("${snapshot.data[i].entry}")
```